# Python, Socket error with accept() function

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I try to run an example code about client and server but some errors appear :

Server :

```
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.sendall(data)
    conn.close()
```

Client :

```
import socket
HOST = '192.168.1.126'    # The remote host
PORT = 50007              # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.sendall('Hello, world')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data)
```

But the errors show up on Server while client working fine.

```
Connected by ('192.168.1.102', 11263)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Win7_Lab\Desktop\Server.py", line 15, in <module>
    conn.sendall("data")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 174, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
[Finished in 5.3s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\Win7_Lab\Desktop\Server.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\Win7_Lab\Desktop]
[path: C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\]
```

Why the errors show up ? and in the line **Connected by ('192.168.1.102', 11263)** 192.168.1.102 is client ip but what is 11263 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing the server connection in the while loop Try to close the connection after the listener is done:

```
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print data
    if not data: break
    conn.sendall(data)
    # conn.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The port `11263` is a so-called [ephemeral port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port?oldformat=true) which is automatically picked by the kernel in order to communicate with your server.